# For loop when generating report in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, automation, report

I am generating a report in MATLAB.

I basically, want to add images to the report based on a str

```
imgs= {'img1.jpg';'img2.jpg'}
import mlreportgen.report.*
import mlreportgen.dom.*

doctype = "pdf"
rpt = Report('ReportABC', doctype);

%Title Page
tp = TitlePage("Title","Test","Subtitle","A report","Image",imgs{1},"Author","Joe Blogs", "PubDate", "Report Published Daily at 12:00 am");
add(rpt,tp);

toc = TableOfContents;
add(rpt, toc);
s1 = Section(sections);
 
  for ii=1:size(imgs,2)
    option1{ii} = Image(which('dss1.jpg'))
    s1 = Section(sections);
    add(s1,option1(ii))
  end

 %s1 = Section(sections);
 %add(s1,img1);


ch1 = Chapter("Introduction");
add(ch1,s1);

add(rpt,ch1);

close(rpt);
rptview(rpt);
```

Here is an example of my code.

What I would like is the report to show the two images in section 1, then my string had 6 images, it would automatically add 6 images in so I don't have to change the code each time.

Comment: What Excel file? I don’t see it referenced in your code anywhere. You already have code that loops over `imgs` and adds them one by one. Is this not working? Where is the problem?

Comment: @CrisLuengo this does not work, I think it is specific to the report generator in matlab, but this add function is not working, I removed the excel part as it was irrelevant

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? Does it give an error message? Does it insert the wrong images? Does it attempt to unionize? Please be specific, it is really hard to solve unspecified problems. And please edit this information into your question.

Comment: @CrisLuengo no images inserts but no error message either, I think its struggling on the add add(s1,option1(ii)) but I am not sure why